# Open an application in Linux at specific coördinates

Tags: linux, gnome, vlc-media-player, xorg

Is there a way to open an application (like VLC or Totem) and tell it to be x pixels wide, y pixels high and start at a given location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many X clients support a [`-geometry` argument](http://www.xfree86.org/current/X.7.html#sect6) (sometimes `--geometry`) which allows you to specify size and/or position of the initial window.

Comment: True. For some reason, though, mplayer doesn't like it when you ask for your window to be larger than the current screen, which renders it useless for me.